# Trying to get a video thumbnail

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get a video thumbnail from a video saved in Documents/ folder and display it in UIImageView inside UITableViewCell. Here is my function to get the thumbnail:

```
- (UIImage*) thumbnailImageForVideo:(NSURL *)sourceURL
{
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:sourceURL];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    NSLog(@"err==%@, imageRef==%@", err, imageRef);
    UIImage *thumbnail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef); // CGImageRef won't be released by ARC
    return thumbnail;
}
```

And here is where I am using it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LibraryCell *libraryCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LibraryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"], [libraryFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    libraryCell.itemImage.image = [self thumbnailImageForVideo:[NSURL URLWithString:videoPath]];

    return libraryCell;
}
```

The app doesn't crash but there is no image. This is what I see in the console:

```
2013-04-13 23:44:46.828 GeekOut[14433:907] err==Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo=0x1f0b4610 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1f0b3220 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12935.)", NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error}, imageRef==(null)
2013-04-13 23:44:46.859 GeekOut[14433:907] err==Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo=0x1dd8c660 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1dd8c5c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12935.)", NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error}, imageRef==(null)
2013-04-13 23:44:46.893 GeekOut[14433:907] err==Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo=0x1f0bec80 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1f0be9b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12935.)", NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error}, imageRef==(null)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your thumbnail extraction code works fine.  The problem is the way you're initializing `NSURL` in **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:**.

Try changing this:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:videoPath]
```

To this:

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]
```